# Batch file to start a program and restart it when that program crashes

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that should start Firefox with an iMacros script, and after that should detect when Firefox crashes, and if it does crash, the batch restarts Firefox again and so on.

But I noticed that Firefox is restarted many times, regardless of if it is crashing or not

I was wondering how I can change this code so it only restarts when Firefox is not responding.

Code:

```
@echo off
:loop
cls
taskkill /F /IM Firefox.exe
cls
taskkill /F /IM crashreporter.exe
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 4000 > nul
set MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1
timeout /t 4 /nobreak
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=macros.iim
set MOZ_NO_REMOTE=
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000000 > nul
goto loop
```

Comment: It restarts Firefox unconditionally every `1000000` milliseconds which is ~16minutes.

Comment: Really??? it's because of this line right? "ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000000 > nul"

Comment: What do I have to do in order to only restart if firefox crashes?

Comment: @wOxxOm if you may awnser :)

Comment: @user3707533 It is very difficult to let code in a batch file run event driven and most often not possible at all. Batch processing with command processor is designed for doing something automated and then end. Event triggered execution of commands using a batch file is outside of the design concept of batch processing. It would be better to code this task in other languages like C++, C#, etc. which support event driven execution by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to use a check, look for example at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20640377/5022761) answer. So in your case, you need to use

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=macros.iim
:loop
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" /fi "status eq running` |find  /i "firefox.exe"  >nul && ( 
timeout 60 /NOBREAK
) || ( 
cls
taskkill /F /IM Firefox.exe
cls
taskkill /F /IM crashreporter.exe
timeout 4 /NOBREAK
set MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=macros.iim
set MOZ_NO_REMOTE=
)
goto loop
```

using your code. This should check if firefox is not responding, and if this is not the case it waits 60 seconds. If it is not responding it goes to your restart code.

Comment: So this checks every 60s if firefox is runnimg, and if firefox doesn't respond, it restarts it right?

Comment: Not only if firefox is running, but if it is running AND not responding. The restart code is yours, so if that doesn't work you need to look at that code... The only difference is I used the timeout command instead of a ping to wait a period of time.

Comment: Did it work? If so you should mark an answer as correct, if not we can continue to try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The START command takes a /WAIT parameter. This means it won't return control back to your batch script as long as firefox is executing. Assuming firefox stops executing when it crashes (which it looks like you are assuming) then just adding the /WAIT parameter will do what you want.